# Buddypress Xprofile Custom Fields Type (Loop user profile field)

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to create a site where the members can search for each other based on various profile fields like "games", "platform", "skill level" etc.

I want to be able to fetch datas on how many people have different tags on them.

Under the skill level for example i have "beginner", "intermediate" and "hardcore" I wanna grab the number from each so i can pull them out like Beginner: 30 people, intermediate: 199 people etc.

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

```
 global $wpdb;

 $results = $wpdb->query( "SELECT count( `user_id`)  FROM `sf_bp_xprofile_data` WHERE `field_id`= 8 AND `value` = 'woman'" );
```

change field id and value according for you